# Universal Image Loader not showing some of the images

Tags: android, image, loader, universal-image-loader

I am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for showing images in my listview in Android. Most of the images are showing perfectly fine, but some other [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) are not working. What could be the cause?

Comment: Can you post your configuration (ImageLoaderConfiguration),
display options (DisplayImageOptions),getView() method code of your adapter and XML layout of your ImageView you load image into?

Comment: I can think of 3 things: the url address is incorrect, the image doesn't exist at that url, there is a bug in the listview control.

Comment: @jeff i have logged the url , the url are returning the image properly  , can you explain a bit what kind of bug can there be in listview control?